# Approach to process huge xml files in C#

Tags: c#

Can someone please guide me with this problem?

In my institution, we process xml files of huge size(max 1 GB) and insert the details into a database table. Per current design, we are parsing xml file with XmlReader and form a xml string with required data, which will then be passed into a stored procedure (xml data type) to insert the details into db.

Now the problem is we are not sure if there would be a better approach other than this ? so please suggest if are any new features available with .Net 3.5 and/or sql server 2005 to handle this in a way better than our approach.

Any help in this reagrd would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is "don't [ab]use xml for that" a valid answer?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: How is that huge?

Comment: @BoltClock, Depends on the area of usage I guess. But imho, 1GB is quite big.

Answer (score 1):

Do you care at all what is in the XML-file? If not, you can just use a `StreamReader` and get the text from the XML and just pass it along to the database.

If you need to validate that the XML is correct, it is a good idea to use `XmlReader`.

However, just dumping 1GB of XML into your database seems a bit weird, what is the purpose of this XML data? Is it a lot of nested elements? Maybe you could de-serialize it and store each object in the appropriet table instead, which would imo lead to a easier understandable design.

There are a couple of things you can think of to make the design of your software easier/better:

- Does more than one XML file occure in the database at once?
- How is the data shared between applications?
- Have you considered using `MemoryMappedFile`?
- Is it possible to de-serialize the XML into entities instead and store them approprietly?

Comment: Thanks for your response Filip!!!.

Our requirement instructs us to process the huge xml file and find a few nodes of it then insert them into db. 
The actual purpose of xml data extracted from the original file is to generate a report for the user. 
Hence we don't dump entire data of xml into our database rather a few nodes of it.
Yes there would be a lot of nested elements present in the xml file.

For the above requirement, does our current approach would be sufficient? Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @FYI, Let's say that you want a nested node, that has nested nodes inside it, you might as well de-serialize it to objects instead, it makes everything easier, and besides you will get it splitted up into different columns in your database as well. Which imho would be a better design than just dumping some nodes into a `text` field. See this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if there are any performance issues it will be with the stored procedure and the database side of things rather that reading the file.

Why are you storing the XML file in a database table? I would suggest using a different solution would be appropriate, but without knowing more details about exactly what it is you are trying to do it is hard to advise.

Comment: Thanks Nick !!!. We are not storing entire xml content into db rather we parse and insert only a few nodes of it. The actual purpose is to show a report to the user with required data came out of the xml file. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

If each first-level element in the xml is a record, i.e.

```
<rootNode>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
</rootNode>
```

Then you could create an `IDataReader` implemention that reads the xml (via `XmlReader`) and presents each as a record, to be imported using `SqlBulkCopy`. Pretty much like my old answer [here](https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/b1d70b504cdee2ad?hl=en).

Advantages:

- `SqlBulkCopy` is **the** fastest way to get data into a database
- stripping it into records makes **appropriate** use of a database, allowing indexing and proper typing
- it doesn't rely on a huge BLOB going over the wire in an atomic way (necessary for the xml data type)